# How do I deal with NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Edge?

Tags: ssl, certificate, https, openssl, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a legacy application with invalid ssl certificat. I want to run the application on Edge, I get the error `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`, but I can run it on google chrome.

I know I have to install a valid ssl certificat, but for now how can I run the application on Edge ?

Comment: "I have to install a valid SSL certificate" - To which certificate store exactly? [Edit] your screenshot instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Installing SSLs is pretty well documented. So, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Try enforcing the site to use Edge's `IE mode` via its [site list XML file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-site-list-manager).  This may give you the familiar IE page allowing access to insecure sites, depending upon how your group policies are configured/enforced.

Comment: I don't need IE mode

Comment: Cert Authority Invalid usually means your machine doesn't trust the root cert in your chain.  Check that the root certificate for your chain is in your trust store.  Maybe your app need to serve up the intermediate (extra downloads done by browser to compensate usually may not work for some apps that need the entire chain), or maybe the root isn't in the trust store at all for some reason.  Strange it would be valid in IE but not Edge as they both look to the machine trust store I believe.